# Javascript callback - Why isn't it working?

Tags: javascript, mysql, callback

How I want my code to work:

1. Website sends a SQL Insert to the database.  (I'm using a POST and Node.js)
2. Website waits for the rowID for the database record that will be created
3. Node.js sends back the rowID that was just inserted
4. DOM is updated

How my code is working:

1. Website sends a SQL Insert to the database.  (I'm using a POST and Node.js)
2. **I wrote a Sleep function because the Website is not waiting for the rowID**
3. Node.js sends back the rowID that was just inserted
4. DOM is updated

I thought I correctly wrote a callback function so this would work. However, the DOM is only correctly updated when I created a sleep function. The code I wrote to get this working is not the proper way to implement this and I would like to do it properly.

```js
//add a record to the table
function addRecord() {
 
 event.preventDefault();
 
 var newTech = document.getElementById("newTechnician");
 
 if(newTech.elements.firstnameInput.value.length === 0 || newTech.elements.lastnameInput.value.length === 0 )
 {
  console.log("User didn't enter any data");
 }
 else {
    
    //stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = 'POST',
  url = '/tech';
  
  //build the url
  var usersInput = "type=insert&First_Name="+newTech.elements.firstnameInput.value+    
       "&Last_Name="+newTech.elements.lastnameInput.value;
   
  http.open(method, url, true);
  
  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  
  function updateDatabase (callback) {
   
   http.send(usersInput); 
   http.onreadystatechange = () => callback();
  }
  
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
     var start = new Date().getTime();
     for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
     }
  }
  
  function callbackFunction () { 
   //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState
   if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    if(http.status >= 200 && http.status < 400){
  
     //added because callback isn't working correctly and isn't waiting until 
     //it receives a response with the rowID from Node.js/mySQL database
     sleep(500);
     
     //add the new row to the table
     var response = JSON.parse(http.responseText);            
   
     //without the sleep function, id is undefined
     var id = response.rowID;

     var table = document.getElementById("technicianTable"); 

     //-1 add record at the end of the table
     var row = table.insertRow(-1);                         

     var newTechID = document.createElement('td');                
     newTechID.textContent = id;
     row.appendChild(newTechID);

     var newFirstName = document.createElement('td');                
     newFirstName.textContent = newTechnician.elements.firstnameInput.value;
     row.appendChild(newFirstName);
     newTechnician.elements.firstnameInput.value = "";

     var newLastName = document.createElement('td');                
     newLastName.textContent = newTechnician.elements.lastnameInput.value;
     row.appendChild(newLastName);
     newTechnician.elements.lastnameInput.value = "";
      
     var newWorkoutDeleteCell = document.createElement('td');             
     var newWorkoutDeleteBtn = document.createElement('input');            
     newWorkoutDeleteBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
     newWorkoutDeleteBtn.setAttribute('name','deleteButtonValue');         
     newWorkoutDeleteBtn.setAttribute('value','Delete');
     newWorkoutDeleteBtn.setAttribute('onClick', 'deleteRecord(' + id + ')');
     var deleteRowID = document.createElement('input');             
     deleteRowID.setAttribute('type','hidden');
     deleteRowID.setAttribute('id', 'identifer' + id);
     newWorkoutDeleteCell.appendChild(deleteRowID);
     newWorkoutDeleteCell.appendChild(newWorkoutDeleteBtn);         
     row.appendChild(newWorkoutDeleteCell);                         
    }
  
   }
  };
  
  updateDatabase(callbackFunction);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reverse your `send` call with setting `onreadystatechange`. You want to register your callback *before* sending the HTTP request:

```
        function updateDatabase (callback) {
            http.onreadystatechange = () => callback();
            http.send(usersInput);  
        }
```

But you may find the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) easier to work with than using the older `XMLHttpRequest` methods. Like @Raymond's suggestion, it's Promise-based. The downside is it's not fully supported in IE or Edge.

If better browser support is needed, try [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), an open source, Promise-based HTTP client library with a lot of community support.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem, I ended up putting my Node.JS MySQL insert function in a promise. That way we know it finishes before we should continue on the backend Node.JS server. I had a hard time with this exact thing, until I switched to promise's. My MySQL functions would complete but the data wouldn't be there in the response.

```
function insert() {
    return new Promise((reoslve, reject) => {
        let results = []; // Store results
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw reject(err); // Reject errors
            console.log("Connected!");
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Result: " + result);
                results.push(result); // Push result to results array
            });
            resolve(results); // We made sure we waited
        });
    })
}

insert().then((response) => {
    // Success, made sure it finishes
    // console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    // Error's
});
```

Basic promise's example

```js
function insert() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('Response')
      }, 500);
      // reject() for errors
  });
}

console.log('This runs first');
// This runs, and wait's for respoinse
insert().then((response) => {
  // We waited for response first
  console.log('Our new promise callback', response);
}).catch((error) => {
   // Error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@benjarwar "reverse your send call with setting onreadystatechange" fixed the issue issue!

Thank you @benjarwar and @Raymond for your help.  I'll read up on Promise because I spent way too much time on this issue.